# Analysis complexity, in for inside for, the 2nd for depeneds from the first one

Tags: java, for-loop, time-complexity

the first loop is running n times.
the second for loop is running logn times.
but the third loop depends on the first loop,
how can I measure the running time(big O notation) if the thirs loop depends on the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use some mathematics here. Lets talk about your 2nd and 3rd loop:

No of iterations in 3rd loop(for c) for each iteration of 2nd loop(for b):

1 = 2^0  ( for b < 1)

2 = 2^1  ( for b < 2)

4 = 2^2  ( for b < 4)

.

.

n = 2^(logn base 2)

sum of above iterations is [GP series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) sum which comes down to :

2((2 ^ logn) -1) / (2-1) which gives n.

now first loop runs n times.

**So overall your code runs in order of n^2.**

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as a friendly advice, you should post the code inside your own post, and not in an external webpage. It is much better that way because we do not have to access external webpages.

Now, for the problem, think about it. For every time the logarithmic loop executes (the second loop), there is a for loop which will do `b` iterations. Then, we can deduce:

`O(n) = a * b * c = (substitute c by b) = a * b * b = a * b² = n * log²(n)`

It makes sense, right? The first loop is executed in a linear time, the second is executed in a logarithmic time, and the third follows the second one, so it is also executed in a logarithmic time, and because they are nested, they can be grouped to a **squared** logarithmic time.